# make a span within a contenteditable div uneditable

Tags: contenteditable, html

I have a contenteditable div, which contains several spans with class dontEdit . Is there a way I can make the spans undeditable, while the rest of the div stays editable.

```
<div contenteditable=true>
    editable1 <span class="dontEdit">uneditable1</span> editable2
</div>
```

Please see the fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/LZpag/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `contenteditable="false"` to each `<span>` element. If you need to do it dynamically, you can use the `contentEditable` property in JavaScript. Note that the following won't work in IE <= 8 because those browsers do not support `document.getElementsByClassName()`, but that's easily worked around if necessary:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("dontEdit");
for (var i = 0, len = spans.length; i < len; ++i) {
    spans[i].contentEditable = "false";
}
```